# The database cannot be opened because it is version 706. This server supports version 655 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have database files in my `App_Data` folder and my web config looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TicketsConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Tickets.mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI;User Instance=True;" 
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I have Default.aspx page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:TextBox ID="LastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="FirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Phone1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Phone2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="DisplayMessage" runat="server" style="color: #FF0000" Visible="false" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TicketsConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Employee]" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Employee] WHERE [EmpID] = @EmpID" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Employee] ([LastName], [FirstName], [Phone1], [Phone2]) VALUES (@LastName, @FirstName, @Phone1, @Phone2)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Employee] SET [LastName] = @LastName, [FirstName] = @FirstName, [Phone1] = @Phone1, [Phone2] = @Phone2 WHERE [EmpID] = @EmpID">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="EmpID" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Phone1" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Phone2" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Phone1" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Phone2" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="EmpID" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataKeyNames="EmpID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpID" HeaderText="EmpID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="EmpID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="LastName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone1" HeaderText="Phone1" SortExpression="Phone1" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone2" HeaderText="Phone2" SortExpression="Phone2" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
        </asp:GridView>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and one Default.aspx.cs page

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TicketsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertIntoEmployee", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = LastName.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Phone1", SqlDbType.NVarChar);//SqlDbType.NVarChar allowed to insert Russian letters
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Phone2", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@LastName"].Value = LastName.Text;
        cmd.Parameters["@FirstName"].Value = FirstName.Text;
        cmd.Parameters["@Phone1"].Value = Phone1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters["@Phone2"].Value = Phone2.Text;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();



        DisplayMessage.Text = "Запись добавлена.";
            DisplayMessage.Visible = true;

    }
}
```

and it throwing this error

```
The database 'G:\SITES\WEBSITE6\APP_DATA\TICKETS.MDF' cannot be opened because it is version 706. This server supports version 655 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
Could not open new database 'G:\SITES\WEBSITE6\APP_DATA\TICKETS.MDF'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.
An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file G:\sites\WebSite6\App_Data\Tickets.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The database 'G:\SITES\WEBSITE6\APP_DATA\TICKETS.MDF' cannot be opened because it is version 706. This server supports version 655 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
Could not open new database 'G:\SITES\WEBSITE6\APP_DATA\TICKETS.MDF'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.
An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file G:\sites\WebSite6\App_Data\Tickets.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Source Error: 


Line 14:     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
Line 15:     {
Line 16:         GridView1.DataBind();
Line 17:     }
Line 18:
```

I thought  there is some problem in connection Strings but for me everything looks fine, and my question how to fix this problem?

Comment: Upgrade your version of SQL Server or recreate the database in the same version of SQL Server that you are using.

Comment: it was created on same DB yesturday it is SQL Server Express 2012. i just  copied .mdf file from DB data folder into folder with my project and changed `ConnectionSting`

Comment: You are attaching the database to something other than SQL Server 2012.

Comment: find out that i was created it in SQL server express 2012 but when i run my application in Visual Studio it is for some reason connect  this mdf file to Sql server express 2008. Na i dont know why

Comment: `Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS` points you to the named instance `SQLEXPRESS` which is presumably SQL Server 2008-based.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Version 706 is a database file from Sql Server 2012
Version 665 is a database file from Sql Server 2008R2 (post SP1 ?)

http://conceptdev.blogspot.com/2009/04/mdf-cannot-be-opened-because-it-is.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is Tested Solution, 1st Connect both Server in your SQL Server Management Studio and then RUN the 1st Code Block

```
--1st Run this (One Time)
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver  
@server='YOUR_SERVER_IP', -- here you can specify the name of the linked server  
@srvproduct='',       
@provider='sqlncli', -- using SQL Server Native Client  
@datasrc='YOUR_SERVER_IP',   -- add here your server name  
@location='',  
@provstr='',  
@catalog='DATABASE_NAME'
```

Then Run this Individually

```
SELECT TOP(100) * 
FROM LOCAL_TABLE A, [YOUR_SERVER_IP].DATABASE_NAME.dbo.TABLE_NAME C
WHERE A.ID=C.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you’re trying to attach to a local db use LocalDb (since vs2012, sql2012), ie:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename= (etc)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the problem was that `aspnetdb.mdf` can't open.

Sometimes this file gets corrupted. The problem was that I can't validate login page.

After deleting(and replacing) my login form control, the problem was solved.

The reason for this was because control from `asp.net` uses `aspnet` membership. I replaced my login control (with javascript) with CSS style and remove all related files and that solved it.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: You should really post your own question. This one here is a few years old. You can link back to this question stating why this doesn't apply to you, or what's different, as well as anything else you've actually tried. Welcome to SO and good luck with your question!